# new Date() with string format 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss' in Firefox

Tags: javascript

Code:

```
new Date(dateStr)
```

Firefox doesn't support new Date('2017-11-11 01:23:45'). I have some solutions but all have to change the original code:

1. change the string value to '2017-11-11T01:23:45' before new Date()

   ```
   new Date(dateStr.replace(' ', 'T'))
   ```
2. use some library like moment

   ```
   moment(dateStr).toDate()
   ```

There are a lot of similar lines of code in my project. How can I solve this without change all those one by one. Maybe override the native Date object?

Comment: *override the native Date object* -> the only way and a generally bad idea... Maybe use a factory instead.

Comment: One other option would be to parse the string and instantiate a date from that. You shouldn't be trying to pass a string into the Date constructor as it is strongly discouraged (see the warning on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)). So basically, you should change your code, hopefully to something where the date creation logic is centralized in one place.

Comment: Thank you. I know it's a bad idea to pass a string into the Date constructor. But it's an old project with quite a lot of similar usages. The date creation logic is everywhere.Seems I have to correct the logic one by one.